# why do i have no adress bar and why is Netflix slow

Tags: netflix

on my computer I downloaded Ubuntu and it worked great, but then one day my address bar didn't show up on my name. I share the computer with my brothers, so I went on their name to see if they had the address bar. They did, and I was stuck without it. please tell me what happened, and how to get it back. also I downloaded Netflix and it is really slow and doesn't work well at at all.

Comment: What address bar? Where?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the Netflix-desktop package, it will always run in fullscreen (but only while using the application) likely due to a compatability issue with silverlight.  To my knowledge, there is no way to change this.  As for the slow video playback, I would assume that it's just another compatability issue, as the netflix package uses the windows version of silverlight, which has not been optimized for Ubuntu.

I'm confused by what you mean when you refer to your "adress bar".  If it is the one on the Ubuntu desktop, make sure you have the "Ubuntu" option selected to the right of your username as you login to the computer.  Other desktop environments (kde, xfce, lxde etc.) can look very different, and many do not show your username in the upper right corner like unity and gnome.  Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

When using netflix-desktop, you can come out of full screen mode by pressing <kbd>F11</kbd>. This is just a functionality of the Firefox browser; it works whenever you're using Firefox. Also, if you run netflix-desktop from the terminal, you can use the

```
netflix-desktop --windowed
```

flag to open the browser in non-full screen mode. Try entering

```
netflix-desktop -help
```

in the terminal for a list of all the options available when running from the terminal.